# Triangular linear system with triangular right hand side in python

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

I have to solve a linear system of equations with multiple right hand sides, A*X=B, where both, A and B are (upper) triangular, real, square matrices. The size is about 200 by 200. Is there a fast method for this in python/numpy?

I was considering looping over the columns:
[edit: included a 7x7 example as requested in the comments.]

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as sp

A=np.array(
[[ 1.          0.44615865  0.39541532  0.24977742  0.0881614   0.26116991   0.4138066 ]
 [ 0.          0.89495389  0.24253783  0.4514874   0.12356345  0.22552021   0.48408527]
 [ 0.          0.          0.88590187  0.03860599  0.19887529  0.03114347  -0.02639242]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.85573357 -0.05867366  0.85120741   0.25861816]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.96641899  0.14020408   0.26514478]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.36844234   0.50505032]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.           0.44885192]])
B=np.triu(np.array(
  [[ 949.43526038  550.35234482  232.34981032 -176.85444188 -143.39220636  198.43783458   60.7140828 ]]
  ).T @ np.ones((1,7)) )

n=A.shape[0]
X=np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(n):
    X[:i+1,i]=sp.solve_triangular(A[:i+1,:i+1],B[:i+1,i])
```

But this does not use fast matrix-matrix operations.

I could also do all right hand sides simultaneously, `X=solve_triangular(A,B)`, but this does not take into account the triangular structure in B.

Finally, I could invert A and multiply with B, `X=inv(A)@B`, but inverting matrices is usually discouraged from.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide an example for `A` and `B`. You don't need to provide a 200x200 array, a 7x7 subarray of your actual arrays should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I couldn't find a single routine which makes use of the triangular structure and uses BLAS3 operations. I ended up using a blocked version of the loop-over-columns approach from my question, treating a bunch of columns at a time.

```
X = np.zeros((n,n))
bs = 32 #block size.
for bst in range(0, n, bs):#bst = block start
    bsn = min(bst + bs, n)#block start next
    X[:bsn,bst:bsn] = sp.solve_triangular(
        A[:bsn,:bsn], B[:bsn,bst:bsn])
```

On the plus side this does use the structure and BLAS3 operations. As the disadvantage you have to tune the block size.